# How to code keras to read my own picture using my trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I used minst to train my own model of number reading, but when I tried to upload my own picture for predicting, it told me an error said "ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 84]"(My model was trained correctly, predicting picture in minst was successful.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications import *
import glob
 
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

img = []
x = []

images = image.load_img("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/num.png", target_size=(28, 28))
x = image.img_to_array(images)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
img.append(x)

print(len(x))
x = np.concatenate([x for x in img])
 
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')
y = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(y, top=3))
```

This is my error:

```
28    #This is printed by "print(len(x))"
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28) for input Tensor("flatten_1_input_3:0", shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 28, 3).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cd1af7600aac> in <module>()
     27 
     28 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')
---> 29 y = model.predict(x)
     30 print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(y, top=3))

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1462 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1452 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1445 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1418 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:372 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:386 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:508 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 84]
```

Minst is a 28x28 picture so this code is using 28x28 picture.
My environment of develop is: "Google Colab" and "Juypter Notebook", and this error I have tried both environment and still getting this error.
Can somebody help?
import tensorflow as tf  # deep learning library. Tensors are just multi-dimensional arrays

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist  # mnist is a dataset of 28x28 images of handwritten digits and their labels
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()  # unpacks images to x_train/x_test and labels to y_train/y_test

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()  # a basic feed-forward model
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())  # takes our 28x28 and makes it 1x784
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))  # a simple fully-connected layer, 128 units, relu activation
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))  # our output layer. 10 units for 10 classes. Softmax for probability distribution

model.compile(optimizer='adam',  # Good default optimizer to start with
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  # how will we calculate our "error." Neural network aims to minimize loss.
              metrics=['accuracy'])  # what to track

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)  # train the model

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)  # evaluate the out of sample data with model
print(val_loss)  # model's loss (error)
print(val_acc)  # model's accuracy
```

[image: This is the picture of num.png]

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit hard to tell without exactly knowing how your model was built and how the num.png looks like. However, from the error message it seems you have two mistakes: You are loading rgb color images (although MNIST and likely your model is trained on greyscale images) and therefore (or this is a second bug) you got the dimensions wrong (3 for RGB and not one for grayscale). 28*3 = 84 is how I would explain the error message:

> but received input with shape [None, 84]

Try to `add rgb_to_grayscale` and `axis=0`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_preprocessing import image
images = image.load_img("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/num.png", target_size=(28, 28))    
x = image.img_to_array(images)
x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x/255.0
img.append(x)

print(len(x))
x = np.concatenate([x for x in img])
 
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')
y = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(y, top=3))
```

Please note that I added x=x/255.0, because I assume that you also forgot to rescale to [0,1]. I assume that if you stick closely to the MNIST ML tutorials you trained your model applying a rescaling to your images in your preprocessing. You have to apply that too.

Update:
It works for me too with passing x directly to model.predict:

```
images = image.load_img("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/num.png", target_size=(28, 28))    
x = image.img_to_array(images)
x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x/255.0

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num_reader.model')
model.predict(x)
```

Comment: ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=28x28 at 0x7FF80C1630F0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>) to a Tensor.
I got this error at line "x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(images)" But I can't tell what is difference between "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=28x28 at 0x7FF80C1630F0>" and <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
isn't that all the same?
I have added the code to let you know how I trained it.

Comment: Updated, can you try again? I added: from keras_preprocessing import image and import tensorflow as tf. Please try it with exactly these import statements. The ValueError tells me that something is wrong with the used procedures along with the packages. So tf.image. is NOT from PIL package.

Comment: Please check the update, I also changed the order, so tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale needs to be after the image loading. Please check again.

Comment: I have added it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I changed the order in the code just a sec ago, sorry for this, can you check again, please make sure that the tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale comes after the image loading. Does the error still show up?

Comment: And I have added the picture I want to predict

Comment: Ok, please check the updated code, it works for me, there is no error. I updated the order and a typo. Let me know the error if you get one.

Comment: Yes, it's behind image loading, and still got this problem

Comment: Yes, because there was a typo, I mixed the x and images. I updated it, can you check again and let me know if the error still occurs? So I am not able to reproduce your error. In my colab it works? If it doesn't work, can you please update your question with what is in your x and what is in your images variable, so that I can check the values.

Comment: It seems it's working, but I didn't trained my model well, cuz it's wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's the epoch number too small, I need to train it more

Comment: Well, that is another question, feel free to open a new question for this and one can check. Make sure to put your complete code into it, then it is easier for other users to follow it. Could be epochs, yes, but also optimizer and learning rate and things like that. A lot of factors can influence this.

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'append'" I got this error at "img.append(x)" What library was lost?

Comment: When I run the code and that line I do not get this error. Try to reset your runtime and try again. If it is just one image it is not necessry to append. You can pass x directly to model.predict, see my update.

Comment: Actually your error does not make sense. Why does it say 'Image' object has no attribute append. It should say 'img' has no attribute append. Something went wrong / you run different parts of the code and it got mixed up, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your train and test labels using to_categorical before fitting the model.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
train_label=to_categorical(train_label)
test_labels=to_categorical(test_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the number of neurons of the output layer if it matches the number of the classes or not.
I have face the same problem, and it turned out that I was setting the output units of the models 2 in binary classification, which should be one.